# Why put delays in Verilog even for some simple assignment?

Tags: verilog

I found there are usually many delays in some Verilog source code even if on some simple statement, such as below. What's the underlying reason of placing such delay?

```
cmd <= #`DEL 32`b0
```

Comment: It's usually for gate-level simulation where you care about how long it takes for signals to propagate through digital logic in order to track down timing problems with the design. Is that what you're asking?

Comment: @godel9 this makes sense. Then for gate level simulation, how to choose the right value for each operation/statement?

Answer (score 3):

Your code isn't VHDL, or any other language I know about. It's presumably meant to be Verilog. In normal usage, you don't do a lot of manual delay specification in either language, and source code with delays in it is automatically generated by tools which write in the required delays (but not normally with delays like this). In older Verilog source code, though, you do frequently see a large number of '#0' delay specifications, as the scheduling model was historically broken.

Answer (score 1):

It's usually for gate-level simulation where you care about how long it takes for signals to propagate through digital logic in order to track down timing problems with the design.

In order to choose the right value for each operation/statement, you would need timing information about the target device, usually from a datasheet or lab measurements.

If you don't have know or have access to this information, it's likely that you don't need this level of detail in your model. It's probably counter-productive to use anything other than actual values, since you'll end up with both false positives and false negatives when you're looking for timing problems.

Answer (score 1):

For gate level verification I would hope that the library used for synthesis had been characterised and appropriate delays added to the base level components. Which would be used instead of the RTL in simulation. In Verilog there should be no need to added delays like this to RTL.

The delays may be added to testbench components to simulate off chip delays and interfaces, or delays between different synthesised sections. To calculate the correct delay requires knowledge of the final layout, length of track etc. External interfaces will specify max and minimum delays.